# Multiple Definition with Multiple Source Files

Tags: c, include, multiple-definition-error

I'm currently writing a C program with multiple header and source files.
I have been running into the problem of multiple definition of function foo.

I understand that I am violating the One Definition Rule, but I am not quite
sure how to work around this issue. I have source files for the two objects,
obj1.c and obj2.c. Because header.h iis included in more than one .c file, it is
causing this error.

Are there workarounds other than eliminating all .c files other than main.c?

```
//header.h (with include guards)
void helper(){}

//obj1.h
// Include function definitions for obj1.c

//obj1.c
#include "obj1.h"
#include "header.h"

//obj2.h
// Include function definitions for obj2.c

//obj2.c
#include "obj2.h"
#include "header.h"

//main.c
#include "obj1.h"
#include "obj2.h"
```

Thank you.

Comment: why are you including `header.h` twice?

Answer (score 3):

In `header.h`, you have:

```
void helper(){}
```

This is a *definition* [and *not* merely a *declaration*].

You want a *declaration*:

```
void helper();
```

In *one* [and *only* one] of your `.c` files, you want a *definition*:

```
void
helper()
{
     // do helpful things ...
     helper_count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it a static inline function.
Ensure that the header has guards preventing multiple includes from a single translation unit.

```c
// header.h
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

static inline void helper() {}

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

open the Project file in notepad, and you will notice the one file has 2 entries.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).